# springroo can't setup gwt

Tags: gwt, spring-roo

I have spring roo 1.1.2. I am creating new project like

```
project --topLevelPackage leraning.roogwt
```

then I setup persistence and add an entity

```
persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY
entity --class ~.MyEntity
field string description
```

setup gwt

```
gwt setup
```

and when I try to package it, compilation error occurs

```
perform package
```

Errors

```
[Thread-8] [ERROR] The import com.google.appengine cannot be resolved
[Thread-8] [ERROR] User cannot be resolved to a type
[Thread-8] [ERROR] The import com.google.appengine cannot be resolved
[Thread-8] [ERROR] UserService cannot be resolved to a type
[Thread-8] [ERROR] UserServiceFactory cannot be resolved
[Thread-8] [ERROR] The import com.google.appengine cannot be resolved
[Thread-8] [ERROR] UserService cannot be resolved to a type
[Thread-8] [ERROR] UserServiceFactory cannot be resolved
[Thread-8] [ERROR] User cannot be resolved to a type
```

and detailed in code

```
[Thread-8] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.0:compile (default) on project roogwt: Compiler errors :
[Thread-8] [ERROR] error at import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
[Thread-8] [ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Thread-8] [ERROR] J:\springroo\gwtroo\src\main\java\leraning\roogwt\server  \gae\UserServiceWrapper.java:3:0::0 The import com.google.appengine cannot be resolved
[Thread-8] [ERROR] error at public User getCurrentUser();
[Thread-8] [ERROR] ^^
[Thread-8] [ERROR] J:\springroo\gwtroo\src\main\java\leraning\roogwt\server\gae\UserServiceWrapper.java:16:0::0 User cannot be resolved to a type
[Thread-8] [ERROR] error at import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService;
[Thread-8] [ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Thread-8] [ERROR] J:\springroo\gwtroo\src\main\java\leraning\roogwt\server\gae\GaeAuthFilter.java:3:0::0 The import com.google.appengine cannot be re..... 
<similar errors in other files>
```

Comment: now I have tried to build project from expenses.roo, there is the same problem with gae (can't import package, can't resolve types, etc)

Comment: Are you getting any maven artifcats missing kind of error? Have you tried updating your maven repo?

Comment: no dependency problems, as dependencies are resolved before compilation but here compilation errors. What do you mean "update maven repo"?

Comment: you seem to be missing some jars from the looks of it. Please check which ones are these.

Comment: May be I am missing something during installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if my solutions is good, but I have just removed all folders from src folder with name gae and now I have built and deployed example gwt project without problems.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with the Roo sample expenses.roo project. I solved it by adding the missing maven dependancy to project.

**From Roo shell run this:**

> dependency add --groupId
>   com.google.appengine --artifactId
>   appengine-api-1.0-sdk --version 1.4.0

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to specify the google app engine as the database while setting up the perrsistence.

**persistence setup --provider DATANUCLEUS --database GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE**

This can avoid the error of can't find google app engine related references.

Comment: This worked!, Thanks! This is the answer that should have been "accepted"

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Roo 1.1.4:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-2374